# Your Route 53 hosted zone for this domain needs to be set as authoritative

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-workmail

I can't see what's not right here.

I'm trying to set up my domain to work with Workmail but keep getting this message, even though it was working initially but stopped around 5am this morning (I still had the error but it was working).

My domain was registered through AWS Route 53 and has a hosted zone with NS records that match the domain.

All the required NS records are present but the dashboard shows them as inconsistent or missing.

I tried setting up a community account so I can ask there, but of course the email verification isn't working now so I can't post any questions.

I'm at a loss as to where to go from here!

Is my only option to delete the hosted zone and start again?

Comment: For info, I deleted the hosted zone and re-added it, no difference but I guess I need to wait for propogation...

Comment: You are not providing details. What are the DNS NS resource records? Those must match the registrar for your domain.

Comment: This is in fact what was wrong. I had updated the NS record to match the nameservers for the domain, but the hosted zone nameservers were different. You would think (at least I did) that registering the domain via AWS and creating the hosted zone on AWS they would be the same, but they are not (always). I had to update the NS record to match the hosted zone, AND update the domain to match the hosted zone. Simple when you know!